# help me identify/find more info about bmx forks with this symbol - &

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

Trying to find out as much as I can about these forks and the logo. Originally the forks were grey and had a big sticker of this symbol ( & ) on one side. As you can see in the picture there is a small engraved & symbol on the bottom of the forks,but when I looked it upon google I couldn’t find anything. Any/all info anyone can help me find would be greatly appreciated !!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Ec7.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

They are, unsurprisingly, called [**And Forks**](https://www.vitalbmx.com/product/guide/Forks,8/And-Forks/23,3648).

A close-up picture showing the logo, courtesy of VitalBMX:

[image]

The only other internet source I found on these is the [following BMX Union interview, from 2011](https://bmxunion.com/on-the-horizon/oth-and-forks/). So it seems that this brand never took off and those forks were quickly discontinued.